# как взаимодействует фронтенд и бекэнд React

Tags: reactjs, frontend, backend

я занимаюсь фронтенд-частью приложения, но фронтенд должен всегда взаимодействовать с бекэндом.
Я знаю, что все это происходит через API и запросы (post/get/delete)
Но не понимаю, какую инфу корректно узнавать у бекендера, а какую я должна знать сама.

Например, у меня задание: реализовать загрузку фотки на сайт - когда нажимаешь на иконку "загрузить" и выбираешь фотку, затем она добавляется. Вот это у меня реализовано и оно и так добавляется туда, зачем тут бекенд и как это связать с моим функционалом?? Я правда не понимаю(((

может быть вы посоветуете какую-то литературу почитать профильную или расскажете, как это работает? благодарю!

Comment: Бек нужен для сохранения этой фотки на сервере... От бека нужно узнать на какой УРЛ слать запрос с фоткой. Так же еще можно уточнить как назвать поле, которое будет содержать ту фотку... Вот посмотри как передали файл на сервер в этой статье. https://myrusakov.ru/js-xhr-file-upload.html

Comment: Еще бывает полезно пойти познакомиться с бэкэндером. Спросить, что есть на бэке, как обращаться к нужным сервисам. Какую инфу ждут и что отдают. Диалог творит чудеса ) По сути бэк - обработчик хотелок пользователя. При хорошем бэке, отправляется запрос, в ответ получаются данные, которые необходимо просто отрендерить с минимальной логикой(ну там цвет выбрать в зависимости от значения и т.д.)

Comment: @ksa большое спасибо за инфу и за ссылку! :))

Comment: @SwaD большое спасибо за ваш ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Когда ты загружаешь фотку, по нажатию на кнопку на фронте, фотка добавляется с твоего компьютера. Бекенд нужен, например, когда тебе нужно получить список товаров с бд. Ты делаешь get запрос с фронта например через fetch или библиотеку AXIOS. На бекенде написан код, который этот запрос принимает и обрабатывает его. Затем бекенд на основе запроса с фронта посылает запрос в бд, где хранится вся информация о товарах (наименование, цена, путь к фото и тд). Бд возвращает данные серверу, а сервер отдаёт их фронту, который всё красиво упаковывает для зрительного представления клиенту. Это если прям в базовых основах

Comment: спасибо! насчет фото - если я его загружаю с компа, то и запрос никакой не нужен, получается?
эта фотка всегда будет в личном кабинете? просто на данный момент все сохраняется при обновлении страницы, но будет ли так же, если я заду с другого компьютера, например? и еще вопрос насчет запросов: я чаще понимаю синтаксис, но мне же всегда нужна инфа от бэка, если он уже реализовал свою часть? что именно мне нужно узнавать? может быть вы курс какой-нибудь сможете посоветовать в целом об этом? не могу никак нормально понять это все(((

Comment: Я так понимаю ты имеешь ввиду картинку, которую ты получаешь с <input type="file"/>. Если да, то в таком инпуте хранится просто путь к твоей картинке. Чтобы её было видать на других компьютерах как раз нужен бекенд. Т.е. ты через такой инпут загружаешь картинку, а потом отправляешь её на сервер через форму например. А уже на бекенде код, который сохранит её в бд.

Comment: Представь например сайт Мвидео. Ты переходишь на этот сайт, в каталог товаров. После перехода в адресной строке будет что-то типо "Mvideo/allGoods". На этой странице тебе выведутся все доступные товары. Когда ты перешла на страницу, фронт уже отправил запрос на бек для получения всех товаров. На беке может быть что-то типо такого кода "app.get("Mvideo/allGoods", function(request, response){ // получить товары из бд и вернуть их клиенту например так response.json(здесь данные, которые пришли из бд)})"

Comment: Вот ссылки на хорошие ресурсы для изучения этой темы: https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/4.1.php

Comment: огромное вам спасибо за отзывчивость и ответы!!